# php цикли и командная строка windows

Tags: php, windows

Здравствуйте! Запускаю php из командной строки windows. PHP скрипт выводит в cmd надпись "Loading...". Как сделать, чтобы после завершения каждого цикла, надпись изменялась примерно как-то так:

```
Loading  
Loading.  
Loading..   
Loading...    
Loading
```

а не писало новую. Как сделать? Вывожу текст в cmd так:

```
echo "Loading...";
```

Comment: Не добавляйте в конце echo - PHP_EOL или '\n' - а просто echo и когда нужно чтобы была новая линия делайте PHP_EOL

Comment: мне нужен не переходит строки, а замена выведенной на немного другую.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script